# Calling Haskell FFI Function Ptrs from C

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I am trying to get the following code to work:

```
sample_hs :: CInt -> (CInt -> CInt)
sample_hs x = (x+)

foreign export ccall sample_hs :: CInt -> (CInt -> CInt)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this in c:

```
pf = sample_hs(2);
result = pf(3); //Should be 5;
```

When I try to do this, however, I get an error message:

> error: too few arguments to function ‘sample_hs’

I am guessing that the interface between the language isn't working how I thought it would. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible, FFI Does allow Higher-Order functions to be exported. Some modifications to your Haskell is required though:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign

foreign export ccall sample_hs :: CInt -> IO (FunPtr Sample)

type Sample = CInt -> CInt
foreign import ccall "wrapper" mkSample :: Sample -> IO (FunPtr Sample)

sample_hs :: CInt -> IO (FunPtr Sample)
sample_hs x = mkSample (x+) 

main = return ()
```

Higher-Order functions are exported in Haskell by using the explicit **FunPtr** type. Just to make it a bit clear I've named the higher ordered type **Sample** in this case. In order to be able to create a function pointer you need to use a "wrapper" function, hence the extra FFI declaration.

I haven't tested this, But it should work fine, It compiles anyway. More on FunPtr [here](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Foreign-Ptr.html#2)

-- **EDIT** I have tested It and it works fine. returns 5 as expected.

If you're by any chance doing this on windows, I have a package on hackage [Hs2Lib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Hs2lib) that would export Haskell functions and compile them to a .DLL automatically for you. It also provides you includes for C/C++ and C#. If You're on Linux however, I'm still working on that.

**shameless plug :P**

Using Hs2Lib the only thing you need in your file is:

```
module Test where

-- @@ Export
sample_hs :: Int -> IO (Int -> Int)
sample_hs x = return (x+)
```

and a simple call to Hs2lib

```
PS C:\Users\Phyx\Desktop> hs2lib .\Test.hs
Linking main.exe ...
Done.
```

The reason for the IO and explicit return is that Int -> (Int -> Int) is just Int -> Int -> Int, since types are right associative. But Int -> IO (Int -> Int) indicates that you want to return a function. It's in IO because creating a function pointer is a side-effecting operation.
For completeness the C file used is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Hs2lib_FFI.h"

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    HsStart();

    CBF1_t pf = sample_hs(2);
    int result = pf(3);
    printf("%d\n", result);

    HsEnd();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So It's pretty plug-n-play. But again, It only works for Windows for now.

Comment: The function signature I was working with was a lot more complex than the example, followed your example and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Although I can't find a clause that specifies it in the FFI, I'm pretty sure that no functions are exported with partial application abilities. The C declaration corresponding to

```
foreign export ccall sample_hs :: CInt -> CInt -> CInt
```

is

```
int sample_hs(int, int);
```

not

```
type int (*function_pointer)(int); // or whatever the right syntax is
function_pointer sample_hs(int);
```

Moreover, the syntax for foreign types forbids exporting higher-order functions -- so function pointers never appear in the declarations on the C side.