# Minimal example of calling a fortran library from go

Tags: go, fortran, ffi

I am looking for a minimal example of the FFI between these two languages, a very simple hello world of a Go program calling a Fortran library.

I want to emphasize I am not looking for external resources, recommendations, or a tutorial, only a minimal code snippet in golang, and the corresponding format in Fortran.

There are plenty of examples on this site of:

- [Calling C from fortran (ifort, gfortran)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633654/calling-c-from-fortran-ifort-gfortran)
- [calling C# from Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871845/calling-c-sharp-from-fortran)
- [Read C++ 'Hello World' from Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463225/read-c-hello-world-from-fortran)
- [Call Go functions from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c)
- Calling C from golang
- [Calling Haskell FFI Function Ptrs from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909395/calling-haskell-ffi-function-ptrs-from-c)
- [Calling python from fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075418/embed-python-into-fortran-90)
- [Calling Haskell from Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196449/calling-dynamically-linked-haskell-code-from-rust)
- [How to call R functions from Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959184/how-to-call-r-functions-from-fortran)

A Go -> Fortran example would be in line with these and useful for other developers.

### Edit to address duplication claim

This question has an answer and the one linked to as this being a duplicate of does not.  Closing and redirecting this question as a duplicate that is likely to be closed with -5 votes would not be useful to stackoverflow users, though both present a reasonable question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are resources and examples of calling fortran from go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345803/where-are-resources-and-examples-of-calling-fortran-from-go)

Comment: Doesn't help to link this to that as a dupe.  This was answered (very well) and that was closed as being off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cgo (https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) seems to provide a functionality for calling C. So I've tried using it for calling Fortran (with go-1.11 + gfortran-8.2 on OSX10.11), which seems to be working for this simple program...

main.go:

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: mylib.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8 -lgfortran
// void hello();
// int  fort_mult( int );
// void array_test1 ( double*, int* );
// void array_test2_( double*, int* );
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    // print a message
    C.hello()

    // pass a value
    fmt.Println( "val = ", C.fort_mult( 10 ) )

    k := C.int( 777 )
    fmt.Println( "val = ", C.fort_mult( k ) )

    // pass an array
    a := []C.double {1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5555}
    n := C.int( len(a) )

    C.array_test1( &a[0], &n )  // pass addresses
    fmt.Println( a )

    C.array_test2_( &a[0], &n )  // no use of iso_c_binding
    fmt.Println( a )
}
```

mylib.f90:

```
subroutine hello() bind(C)
    print *, "Hello from Fortran"
end subroutine

function mult( x ) result( y ) bind(C,name="fort_mult")  ! can use a different name
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
    integer(c_int), value :: x
    integer(c_int) :: y

    y = x * 10
end function

subroutine array_test1( arr, n ) bind(C)   ! use iso_c_binding
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_double
    integer(c_int) :: n
    real(c_double) :: arr( n )

    arr(:) = arr(:) * 100.0d0
end subroutine

subroutine array_test2( arr, n ) ! no use of iso_c_binding (e.g. for legacy codes)
    integer :: n
    double precision :: arr( n )   ! or real(8) etc

    arr(:) = arr(:) * 2.0d0
end subroutine
```

Compile:

```
gfortran -c mylib.f90
go build main.go
./main
```

Result:

```
 Hello from Fortran
val =  100
val =  7770
[100 200 300 400 555.5500000000001]
[200 400 600 800 1111.1000000000001]
```

Comment: My usual answer is: "If you can call C from language <x>, you can call Fortran."  (This doesn't extend to C++.) Fortran has extensive C interoperability features. The biggest hurdle, especially with non-compiled languages, is finding the mechanism to bind to compiled code. Once you have that, the rest is straightforward (you MUST stick to the C interoperability features, or else you can create headaches.)

Comment: That’s great and news to me: I expected something special would be necessary  owing to array indexing column transposition or something.

Comment: You certainly need to take array ordering into account, but that has no effect on doing the call.

Comment: @Steve Lionel, in this case, by “you MUST stick to the C interoperability features” you mean the “use iso_c_binding” example rather than the example without?

Comment: No - it is a common misconception that using ISO_C_BINDING makes things interoperable. The key in Fortran is the language-binding-attribute BIND(C). When this is specified on a procedure, variable or type declaration, it imposes rules and behaviors compatible with a "companion C processor". On a procedure, for example, it means no hidden arguments, and the ability to pass by value. On a type it means no padding that a C compiler wouldn't do. ISO_C_BINDING is a help, to be sure, but on its own it does nothing.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  Found this, looks helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info